# Dynamic struct member damaged while passing to function using CUDA/NVCC

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm experimenting with CUDA and I ran into a very strange bug. I have the following files (tl;dr, skip them):

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "list.hpp"

void print_graph(Graph& g);

void init(Graph& g) {
    g.list = new List<int>;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        g.list->push_back(j+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Graph g;    
    init(g);

    print_graph(g);

    delete g.list;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#include "list.hpp"

#ifndef _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_

struct Graph {
    int foo;
    double bar;

    List<int> *list;
};

#endif
```

**printer.cu**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "list.hpp"

#include <cstdio>

void print_graph(Graph& g) {
    List<int>::iterator it; 

    for (it = g.list->begin(); it != g.list->end(); it++) {
        printf("%d\t", *it);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

**list.hpp**
Contains a class named List, similar to STL list. Becouse of it's length, code omitted, can be foud here: [Custom list source](https://gist.github.com/972481)

If I compile and run this, I get a segfault. **It works as expected, if** I issue any of the following changes:

- rename printer.cu to printer.cc, so nvcc is out of the game.
- **change the order** of definition of foo and bar in `struct Graph` (!)
- **change the type** of `bar` (doesn't work if I change the type of `foo`)

Still doesn't work if I prefix print_graph with `__host__`.

The segfault occurs becouse the Graph variable doesn't arrive in print_graph. It's list member contains memory trash, so the listing will fail. (I can't pass any other member value)

So my question is: What did I miss? What the hell is going on? Thanks for the read, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your data alignment compiler flags - sounds like a classic non-aligned struct problem from the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue of alignment requirements in structures is discussed in some detail in Chapter 3 of the CUDA programming guide. The short answer is passing -malign-double to nvcc should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input. As it turned out, I have to pass -malign-double to g++ while compile main.cpp, nvcc passes it automatically.